# Boundary loop of selected faces

Tags: modeling, edges

There was a couple of weeks before, Blender version which lets you determine boundary loop of seleced faces in edit mode.

I can't find how to activate this addon in todays build.

https://builder.blender.org/download/

Operator was called *boundary loop* in edit mode.
Could you tell me how to get this ?

Comment: Exists in 2.78a.

Comment: How come it's not in the latest version?

Comment: 2.78a *is* the latest, official release at least

Comment: Care to point to an image or a document about the function you are looking for ... boundary loop may seem like a very obvious term to yourself ... but not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you refering to this?

**Boundary Loop**

Reference

Mode: Edit Mode –> Edge select mode
Menu: Select ‣ Select Boundary Loop
Select Boundary Loop does the opposite of Select Loop Inner-Region, based on all regions currently selected, it selects only the edges at the border(contour) of these islands. It can operate in any select mode, but when in Face mode it will switch to Edge select mode after running.

All this is much more simple to illustrates with examples:

[image]

The steps I took to use Select boundary loop in version blender 2.77

1. Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.
2. Make sure you are in select face mode.
3. Select the faces to be converted to edge boundary selection.
4. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and select "Select Boundary loop"
5. That's all.

[image]

If your command isn't there, make sure you downloaded the official release.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have that option in edit mode. I'm using daily build because official release 2.78a is not working wih GPU render in Cycles.

Comment: What GPU are you using at the moment? Intel or AMD? Does OpenCL work for you?

Comment: I have AMD 7870 and some older core i3. OpenCL does not work for now but there was notice released that it will be fixed in January.